# How to transmit a force to child rigid bodies in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I have several `rigidBody` (A,B,C) attached together with joints.
A is the parent, B its child, and C the child of B, which schematically gives that : A-joint-B-joint-C

Parenting doesn't seem to affect physics in any manner. 
Also when I add a force to A, B rotate relatively to A and C rotates relatively to B then the moves of B and C are late. Even with `fixedJoint` which is really unrealistic. Even by increasing the solver iteration count it's still far from good.

Is there a setting to make the force applied to A distributed between A, B and C to make the group moves like one thing ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed joints DO make the connected objects act as a single body (with optional limits).  However, if you apply force to just one of these objects, AND this object's center of mass is not in the same position as the full assembly's center of mass, a rotational motion would (and SHOULD) be introduced.

Two ways I can think of around this:

One would be to divide up the force into multiple parts, each with the same direction, but a magnitude proportional to the mass of the object it would be applied to (Sum F = Total F).  Then apply each of these forces to each of your objects in the assembly.

The other would be to compute the center of mass of your assembly of objects, and use the [`ApplyForceAtPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html) function, rather than the basic `ApplyForce` function.

I should mention, I've had poor luck using BOTH the hierarchy, AND joints to connect objects together.  So, I'd suggest avoiding making them children of each other, if you can.